# max_connections in one of two databases, same config

Tags: mysql, google-cloud-platform

**tl;dr: mysql db hits 'too many connections' on lighter workload than another one with heavier load with the same config, with the same webapp**.

Hello! I'm trying to figure out a weird 'issue' with one of our Mysql databases. I already checked the relevant configurations I know that help with the error, but I'm certain the current settings are fine for our needs. Let me elaborate:

While looking around the GCP panel for other things, I noticed our VM instance (small, 2 vcores and 8gb ram) going at 99-100% cpu usage. I thought someone was testing heavy queries on it and moved on, but hours later the usage wasn't going down, so I looked a bit into it.

Long history short: I noticed that there were A LOT of mysql threads idling along another bunch of tomcat threads. I restarted the tomcat service and the cpu usage went down, but a while testing the webapp again, I hit the "too many connections" error.

I know about the max_connections setting, but that's when the title comes into place: We have two servers, our current prod server in-house and our GCP VM instance that we will use to host our most used app (Both servers have their own database). We pretty much kept the same configuration as it was already tested and working fine. Our prod server also hosts two other applications, one that its in alpha and only testers can get into and another that its in beta, and both of these apps demand more of the database, so it has three apps currently in use. More importantly, that server has over 30 days since our last update and the cloud VM has around half that time.

I double checked the configurations of both servers and can confirm that they are the same.

**My question is then what could be causing the database to hit it's limits?** The prod server is being hit with the exact same load (if not more) from one of the apps while handling more connections.

Both servers are running MySql 8 (Same configuration), the VM is running the app on Tomcat 9 in Ubuntu 20.04 and the prod server uses Tomcat 8.5.57 with Ubuntu 18.04. Prod server is an old Opteron 4274 HE with 16Gbs of ram, but I doubt it's a hardware limitation or something do to directly with the Ubuntu version. Both servers have max-connections at 151, wait-timeout of 8 hrs, thread-cache-size of 9, thread-handling as 'one-thread-per-connection' and thread-stack of 286720. These are the settings I know can help with the problem, but I can add more info if needed. Finally, the db in the cloud is not Cloud SQL (That will come in the future, tho). Any feedback or idea on what's going on is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Probably a badly configured connection pool, but that's a guess. You need to trace back the connections.

Comment: You are probably not using connection pools and failing to close connections when the requests complete. Your question does provide details that can solve your problem. You will need to involve your app developers to do a code review on database connection management.

Comment: It is true that we need to review some things, as we recently rolled programmed db backups and a task scheduler feature. And about the connection pool, I honestly don't know. I do know that our Tomcat servers were pretty much out-of-the-box installations before I was given this role (I'm technically a dev). We may not even have actual connection pools. I'll look into it. Thanks!

Comment: Indeed, neither webapp have a connection pool and they all are using DataSources that literally say in bolds "Not for use in Production Environments". I'll try implement HikariCP on them, but I've never used Hikari's ConnectionProvider for multiple tenants. So far, the VM instance hasn't spiked to max cpu usage either, which bothers me. I'll try to find something in the logs.